# What does ^Z mean?

Tags: linux, centos, keyboard-shortcuts, background-process

I tried using ^Z to send and application to the background(to then use `fg` to restore) but I notice that it says "Stopped" and in another terminal while monitoring htop, everything just freezes.

Is there a way I can send to background without stopping/suspending the process?

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` sends `SIGSTOP` to the application.  I'm afraid that there is no other way to send an application into background.

Comment: @devnull `kill -s SIGSTOP` from another terminal?

Comment: @Graeme I'm not sure what you mean, but if you have the PID of the process in question then you could say `kill -STOP <PID>` from another terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Executing a background job**

Appending an ampersand ( & ) to the command runs the job in the background.

For example, when you execute a find command that might take a lot time to execute, you can put it in the background as shown below. Following example finds all the files under root file system that changed within the last 24 hours.

```
find / -ctime -1 > /tmp/changed-file-list.txt &
```

**Sending the current foreground job to the background using CTRL-Z
    and bg command**

You can send an already running foreground job to background as explained below:

Press CTRL+Z which will suspend the current foreground job.
Execute `bg` to make that command to execute in background.
For example, if you’ve forgot to execute a job in a background, you don’t need to kill the current job and start a new background job. Instead, suspend the current job and put it in the background as shown below.

```
find / -ctime -1 > /tmp/changed-file-list.txt

[CTRL-Z]
[2]+  Stopped                 find / -ctime -1 > /tmp/changed-file-list.txt

bg
```

**View all the background jobs using jobs command**

You can list out the background jobs with the command jobs. Sample output of jobs command is

```
jobs
[1]   Running                 bash download-file.sh &
[2]-  Running                 evolution &
[3]+  Done                    nautilus .
```

**Taking a job from the background to the foreground using fg command**

You can bring a background job to the foreground using `fg` command. When executed without arguments, it will take the most recent background job to the foreground.

**fg**

If you have multiple background jobs, and would want to bring a certain job to the foreground, execute jobs command which will show the job id and command.

In the following example, fg %1 will bring the job#1 (i.e download-file.sh) to the foreground.

```
jobs
[1]   Running                 bash download-file.sh &
[2]-  Running                 evolution &
[3]+  Done                    nautilus .

# fg %1
```

**Kill a specific background job using kill %**

If you want to kill a specific background job use, kill %job-number. For example, to kill the job 2 use

```
kill %2
```

All the above contents are taken from this [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/).